# Split a column in pandas twice to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a column "Nome_propriedade" with complete addresses, such as establishment name, streets, neighborhood, city and state

It always ends with the name of the city and state. With this pattern:

```
Nome_propriedade
"Rod. BR 386, bairro Olarias/Conventos, Lajeado/RS"
"Fazenda da Várzea - zona rural, Serro/MG"
"Cidade do Rock - Jacarepaguá, Rio de Janeiro/RJ"
"Área de extração de carnaúba - Povoado Areal, zona rural, Santa Cruz do Piauí/PI"
"Pastelaria - Av. Vicente de Carvalho, 995, Loja Q, Vila da Penha, Rio de Janeiro/RJ"
```

I want to create two new columns, "city" and "state", and fill them with the last values found in column "Nome_propriedade". I also want to stip those away from Nome_propiedade.

```
                           Nome_propriedade                 City State
      Rod. BR 386, bairro Olarias/Conventos              Lajeado    RS
             Fazenda da Várzea - zona rural                Serro    MG
            Cidade do Rock - Jacarepaguá...       Rio de Janeiro    RJ
Área de extração de carnaúba - Povoado A...  Santa Cruz do Piauí    PI
Pastelaria - Av. Vicente de Carvalho, 99...       Rio de Janeiro    RJ
```

Please anyone know how I can create these two columns?

I can not do a general split because I just want to separate the city and state information. Other information may remain unchanged.

Comment: Are they always comma-separated and slash separated?

Comment: Thank you. Yes in the end it is always ", city/state". The problem is that before that there are also other commas

Comment: @ReinaldoChaves I made various edits to make the question more reusable. Hope you don't mind! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you think about:

```
import pandas as pd
propiedades = ["Rod. BR 386, bairro Olarias/Conventos, Lajeado/RS",
               "Fazenda da Várzea - zona rural, Serro/MG",
               "Cidade do Rock - Jacarepaguá, Rio de Janeiro/RJ",
               "Área de extração de carnaúba - Povoado Areal, zona rural, Santa Cruz do Piauí/PI",
               "Pastelaria - Av. Vicente de Carvalho, 995, Loja Q, Vila da Penha, Rio de Janeiro/RJ"]
df = pd.DataFrame({"Nome_propriedade":propiedades})

df[["City", "State"]] = df["Nome_propriedade"].apply(lambda x :x.split(",")[-1]).str.split("/",
                                                                                           expand=True)
```

**UPDATE**
If you then want to delete these infos from `Nome_propriedade` you can add this line

```
df["Nome_propriedade"] = df["Nome_propriedade"].apply(lambda x :",".join(x.split(",")[:-1]))
```

Comment: Thank you all. It worked. But I just realized now that the ideal would also be, after creating the columns,  deleting the information ", city/state" that was spare in column "Nome_propriedade"

Comment: @user32185, @ReinaldoChaves  This is good but Using `str` you can win a lot of time avoiding apply. Have a look at it. Might be helpful for future.

Comment: You are right about `apply` usage. For sure for massive dataframes your solution is better.

Answer (score 3):

You need to split the string in the column by `,`, takw the last element in the list and split it by `/`. That list is your two columns.

```
pd.DataFrame(list(df['Nome_propriedade'].str.split(',').apply(lambda x: x[-1]).str.split('/')), columns=['city', 'state'])
```

Output:

```
                   city    state
0               Lajeado    RS
1                 Serro    MG
2        Rio de Janeiro    RJ
3   Santa Cruz do Piauí    PI
4        Rio de Janeiro    RJ
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an effective solution avoiding the tedious `apply` and simply sticking with `str-operations`.

```
df["Nome_propriedade"], x = df["Nome_propriedade"].str.rsplit(', ', 1).str
df["City"], df['State'] = x.str.split('/').str
```

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd

propiedades = [
    "Rod. BR 386, bairro Olarias/Conventos, Lajeado/RS",
    "Fazenda da Várzea - zona rural, Serro/MG",
    "Cidade do Rock - Jacarepaguá, Rio de Janeiro/RJ",
    "Área de extração de carnaúba - Povoado Areal, zona rural, Santa Cruz do Piauí/PI",
    "Pastelaria - Av. Vicente de Carvalho, 995, Loja Q, Vila da Penha, Rio de Janeiro/RJ"
]

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Nome_propriedade":propiedades
})

df["Nome_propriedade"], x = df["Nome_propriedade"].str.rsplit(', ', 1).str
df["City"], df['State'] = x.str.split('/').str

# Stripping Nome_propriedade to len 40 to fit screen
print(df.assign(Nome_propriedade=df['Nome_propriedade'].str[:40]))
```

Returns:

```
                           Nome_propriedade                 City State
0     Rod. BR 386, bairro Olarias/Conventos              Lajeado    RS
1            Fazenda da Várzea - zona rural                Serro    MG
2              Cidade do Rock - Jacarepaguá       Rio de Janeiro    RJ
3  Área de extração de carnaúba - Povoado A  Santa Cruz do Piauí    PI
4  Pastelaria - Av. Vicente de Carvalho, 99       Rio de Janeiro    RJ
```

If you'd like to keep the items:

```
df["City"], df['State'] = df["Nome_propriedade"]\
                            .str.rsplit(', ', 1).str[-1]\ 
                            .str.split('/').str
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach I can see is, for a single example:

```
example = 'some, stuff, here, city/state'
elements = example.split(',')
city, state = elements[-1].split('/')
```

To apply this to the column in your dataframe:

```
df['city_state'] = df.Nome_propriedade.apply(lambda r: r.split(',')[-1].split('/'))
df['city'] = [cs[0] for cs in df['city_state']]
df['state'] = [cs[1] for cs in df['city_state']]
```

For example:

```
example2 = 'another, thing here city2/state2'
df = pd.DataFrame({'address': [example, example2],
                   'other': [1, 2]})
df['city_state'] = df.address.apply(lambda r: r.split()[-1].split('/'))
df['city'] = [cs[0] for cs in df['city_state']]
df['state'] = [cs[1] for cs in df['city_state']]
df.drop(columns=['city_state'], inplace=True)
print(df)
#                             address  other   city   state
# 0     some, stuff, here, city/state      1   city   state
# 1  another, thing here city2/state2      2  city2  state2
```

**Note:** some of the other answers provide a more efficient way to unpack the result into your dataframe. I'll leave this here because I think breaking it out into steps is illustrative, but for efficiency sake, I'd go with one of the others.

Comment: I think it should be: elements = example.split(',')

Comment: @Joe I don't think it matters since he just wants to get the city and state. Since they are always at the end, a regular `str.split()` should separate them out and they'll be the last element in the resulting list. Unless I hear otherwise from OP.

Comment: For a city with space, like Rio de Janeiro matters

Comment: @Joe Good point! Looks like my answer is identical to some others then. Deleting.

Comment: You answered as first, you can leave it :)